# Entity Framework Core OwnsOne Create Seperate Table Instead Of Properties In In Same Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core V3.1.4 . and I have these models. I want to use TPH hierarchey . But Entity Framework migration create seperate table for each owned entity.

Can anyone say which part of my code is incorrect ?

```
public abstract class Person
{
    protected Person()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}

public class LegalPerson : Person
{
    public NationalId NationalId { get; set; }
}

public class IndividualPerson : Person
{
    public FullName FullName { get; set; }
}
```

And this entity configurations :

```
public class PersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Persons");
        }
    }

    public class LegalPersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LegalPerson>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LegalPerson> builder)
        {
            builder.OwnsOne(p => p.NationalId);
        }
    }

public class IndividualPersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IndividualPerson>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IndividualPerson> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(p => p.FullName);
    }
}
```

when I execute "add-migration initial" command the migration file created like this .

```
    public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Persons",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                Discriminator = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Persons", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Persons1",
            columns: table => new
            {
                IndividualPersonId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Persons1", x => x.IndividualPersonId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Persons1_Persons_IndividualPersonId",
                    column: x => x.IndividualPersonId,
                    principalTable: "Persons",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Persons2",
            columns: table => new
            {
                LegalPersonId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                Code = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Persons2", x => x.LegalPersonId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Persons2_Persons_LegalPersonId",
                    column: x => x.LegalPersonId,
                    principalTable: "Persons",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Persons1");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Persons2");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Persons");
    }
}
```

and my DatabaseContext :

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(PersonConfiguration).Assembly);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your `DbContext` look like? Especially the `DbSet`

Comment: Somewhere is your context `OnModelCreating` you have something which calls `SetTableName` for owned entities,

Comment: I added DbContext codes to my question